# How can we get Jquery event to work by passing name attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery

`var name = "ext_col_02[0][]";`

This works

```
j$( "input[name='ext_col_02[0][]']" ).change(function() {
   console.log("I am called!");
});
```

But this doesn't

Unable to figure what has been missed here.

```
function fillData(data, select_id) {
  j$(select_id).children().remove();
  var name = j$(select_id).attr('name');
  name = name + "[]";
    if(display_checkbox){
        j$( "input[name='"+name+"']" ).change(function() {
            console.log("I am called!");
        });
        j$.each(data, function(key, value){
            j$(select_id).append('<input type="checkbox" name="'+name+'" value="'+ key +'">' + value + '</input>');
        });
    }else if(display_checkbox === undefined){
      j$(select_id).append('<option value="">{/literal}{'/label/no_select'|translate}{*選択なし*}{literal}</option>');
      j$.each(data, function(key, value){
          j$(select_id).append('<option value="'+ key +'">' + value + '</option>');
      });
    }
    j$(select_id).trigger('change',[true]);
}
```

Elements are added dynamically.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: is the element added dynamically?

Comment: Show us your code, we can't tell you anything from what you've shown us so far.

Comment: @Varun Yes element is added dynamically

Comment: @Zenoo Hope it's possible to tell something now.

Comment: @user202729 Thank you, will keep that in mind.

Comment: Did you try dropping a `console.log()` to see what was the actual value of your variable `name` ?

Comment: After some more thoughts, "lying" seems quite offensive (yes, I know, you don't know what's wrong) but basically you can be misinforming us about what's wrong and make it harder for us to helping you. As for [mcve], having code that can make a working (read: print something to the output and that demonstrates your problem) jsfiddle.com or tryitonline.net link can be helpful.

Comment: `name = name + "[]";` this is wrong unless value of `name` is `ext_col_02[0]`

Comment: @user202729 I understand, i will make sure to create a working model.
Thank You!

Comment: @vinayakj Yes, value of `name` ` is `ext_col_02[0]`